# How to extract a range of paragraphs from an existing docx file using python-docx

Tags: python, python-docx, text-extraction

I want to extract everything in between “” from a docx file.

I am not sure how, so I was planning only to import a specific range of paragraphs. The range of paragraphs in-between “” is 12 through 25.

This is what I have so far, and I can only see one paragraph at a time.

```
import docx
document = docx.Document('test.docx')
for para in document.paragraphs:
    fullText = []
    print(para.text)
    fullText.append(para.text)
    '\n'.join(fullText)
```

If I want to see paragraph 12th. I can only insert one number at the time (not a range)

```
document.paragraphs[12].text
```

Can you help me either extract a range of paragraphs OR import everything in-between “” from the .doxc file?

Thanks, and please let me know if something isn't clear

Comment: `document.paragraphs[11:25]` will give you a list of the paragraphs from the 12th to 25th position.

Comment: Thanks @scanny  
Yes, I have tried document.paragraphs[11:25]  
This is how the list looks:  
[<docx.text.paragraph.Paragraph at 0x1c9efeeb190>,  
 <docx.text.paragraph.Paragraph at 0x1c9efeeb1f0>,  
 <docx.text.paragraph.Paragraph at 0x1c9efeeb280>,  
 <docx.text.paragraph.Paragraph at 0x1c9efeeb310>,  
 ...]  
    
    Also if I try:    
document.paragraphs[11:25].text  
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'text'    

Where I cannot see the .text or not sure how to work around this list to do some .strip/.replace etc. Any ideas?

Comment: There is nothing in `python-docx` that puts paragraphs together into a continuous block of text. You'll need to do that for yourself. This [11:25] slice just gives you the paragraphs you want. Maybe `"\n".join(document.paragraphs[11:25])` is what you're looking for.